# Check if device can decode video or not using Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, decode

I'm using [VR view](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview) in my Ionic (Cordova) app. VR view's docs state that "some older devices cannot decode video larger than 1080p (1920x1080)".

In my app, the user downloads the video file first, so it's not streaming the video.

I have two videos: one for newer devices (in 4k), and one for the older devices (in 1080p). I want to check if the device is capable of decoding the 4k video. If not, it should download the 1080p video.

How could I check if a device is capable of decoding 4k? I was thinking about trying to play a very short baked-in 4k video and catching the error, but I can't get it to work without the video player showing up. It should be done in the background.

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much for native Cordova APIs that respond with what is the maximum supported playback resolution. I personally would try a more elegant approach, just getting the device's resolution and seeing if it is above HD or equal-below HD resolution.

Use the following to figure out the display size in pixels:

```js
function getDeviceDimension() {
    console.log("Device Dimension using PhoneGap");
    console.log("Width = " + screen.width);
    console.log("Height = " + screen.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is it safe to assume that a device will always be capable of decoding a video that has the same dimensions as the device?

Comment: I would say it's safe to assume it can decode larger than the screen resolution (some chips can downscale natively), but in any case I would also code the approach of handling the failed video playback you described in the original post as its a great fallback to have. If your question has been answered please mark it as such. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your approach, but I'm unable to find the correct screen width and height. Testing it with a One Plus One (1080x1920 pixels), it gives me 360x640. Visiting www.whatsmyscreensolution.com with the phone gives the same values.

Comment: What browser did you use on this phone? This looks like a browser bug.

Comment: Google Chrome. Testing it from withing the app (cordova) gives the some wrong values.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. :/

Comment: Another reason why I don't wish to use this approach: the video is played in VR (split screen), meaning that if you use a 1080p video, the part of the video you actually see is 270, not 1080. Therefore, devices that are 1920x1080 do benefit from a 4k video, and shouldn't get a 1080p video if they are capable of encoding 4k.